# How to work email subscribe in WordPress?

Tags: plugins, theme-development, themes, email

There are many website those are using new WordPress theme as email subscribe option, like the below image

http://postimg.org/image/6kh8b1wfb/

and I wish I will add this subscribe option in my theme.I have styling idea but I haven't any WordPress functional idea how to working the subscribe option. I searched google but didn't got any information about it.

So I need informational article on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many WordPress plugins that let you manage your email subscription. But overall this is not recommended, mainly because it creates a **heavy load** on the server. What will inevitably create a problem with the hosting service.

In my experience, it is advisable to work with professional external services. For various reasons among which I highlight:

- They make sending mail (high load)
- They have good design tools
- They know a lot about how to make your mails do not fall as SPAM

These services have different forms of design that attach easily with WordPress themes. An example is **Mailchimp.com**. But there are others.

This article can help you with more information. I hope you find it useful.

[WPBeginner - Why You Should Never Use WordPress to Send Newsletter Emails](http://www.wpbeginner.com/opinion/why-you-should-never-use-wordpress-to-send-newsletter-emails/)